# Docker install failed on windows 10 host

Tags: docker, chocolatey

Users are unable to install docker applicaton using choco on Windows 10.

Event log message:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {8D8F4x3-3xx4-4xx7-8xx9-FC3xxx9} and APPID 
>   {F7xxxA9-012C-4xx5-9DF-2A4D3} to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID
>   (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the
>   application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security
>   permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative
>   tool.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Windows UAC (User Account Control) stopping the installation. The current user isn't administrator or does not have enough privileges on the current system.

There are multiple solutions for that. Choose one of the following:

- start the command prompt elevated (as Administrator) and re-run the choco installation.
- disable UAC in system preferences or with [msconfig](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296719.aspx)
- grant the current user local administrator privileges